# Alternative for Folder.WellKnownFolderName for older Exchange versions

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I use Folder.WellKnownFolderName to detect folder type, but it was introduced only in Exchange 2013. Also it doesn't work with "Clutter" folder. Can i use another Folder property to determinate exchange folder type?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [FolderClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.folderclass(v=exchg.80).aspx) property. That tells you the type of folder (Mail, Calendar, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, i saw this property. But for some foldes with unique WellKnownFolderName it's not unique

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all the `WellKnownFolderName`s you care about, and fetch the corresponding `Folder`s individually by passing `Folder.Bind` a `FolderId` created with the constructor that takes a `WellKnownFolderName`. The `FolderId` of the returned `Folder` will have its unique ID set.  Then just keep track of the `FolderId`-to-`WellKnownFolderName` mapping.